# Is it possible to get exact command when triggering shortcut?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, command, display, desktop-shortcuts

For example, I want to know what command invokes when I hit `Fn` + `F12` to increase brightness. Can I get this or any other command when I trigger some shortcut (what's happening behind the scenes) somehow?

Distro: Debian 10 (stable) XFCE

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are referring to a laptop keyboard and working in a desktop manager. Not sure what distro or manager you are using, but many allow to you map keyboard shortcuts. For example if you are using Ubuntu and gnome desktop you can go to settings/devices/keyboard and see the mappings.

If you are on the console and want to see the linux key mapping you can run infocmp.

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

Comment: Debian 10 (stable) on XFCE. When I go to "keyboard shortcuts", it doesn't tell me what's happening behind the scenes when I press Fn + F12, and that's exactly what I want to find out.